# mount point and distributed folder

Tags: linux, linux-networking, arch-linux

I have 10 unix servers and in that `/home` is common in all the unix servers and any update in `/home` of any server is getting reflected in all the servers.

How is this done? and also please let me know how to find out the mount point of `/home` in this case?

Comment: They are *your* ten servers, you tell *me* how you did this amazing thing. :)

Comment: @Kaz: Perhaps someone else did it and then took a new job ?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the `/etc/fstab` file. This contains information on all the mount points that the system mounts automatically.

One line will almost certainly refer to `/home` and this is the one you will look for. It will probably look something like this:

```
203.0.113.240:/export/home  /home   nfs     rw,nosuid,nodev     0 0
```

In this case we see from the third field that it is an NFS mount. Your file will tell you exactly what is going on in your case.

Comment: If you can't find the according lines in `/etc/fstab` it's also possible that your homes get mounted via automount. if you run this as root `mount | grep home` you should see all the currently mounted filesystems that have `home` in their path. by doing `ps axu | grep automount` you should see if there is an automount daemon running

Comment: There are other "network file system" or "distributed filesystem" possibilities too (AFS, SSHFS, etc.)

Comment: Maybe he'll eventually come back and tell us all what he found.